# Paypal option issue on Opencart

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

We're using the built in Paypal Standard payment system on Opencart but it is not pulling the option price to Paypal.

Here is the code we have in our pp_standard.tpl file

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['model']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['price']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="weight_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['weight']; ?>" />
<?php $j = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option)  { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="on<?php echo $j; ?>_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $option['value']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="os<?php echo $j; ?>_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $option['price']; ?>" />
<?php $j++; ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I think the line that is the issue is this

```
<input type="hidden" name="os<?php echo $j; ?>_<?php echo $i; ?>"   
  value="<?php echo $option['price']; ?>" />
```

But I am not sure what to change it to for Paypal to pull the correct price

Here is the code that shows the price in the cart.tpl file

```
<?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
- <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?>
- Price: <?php echo $option['price']; ?></small><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use counter with paypal standard hidden inputs like `amount`, `item_name` and other hidden inputs inside `foreach`

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['price']; ?>" />
```

in your case, paypal is looking request from `input="amount"` and you are posting request through `input="amount_1"`